# c# , how to not repeat a long chain of method calls to check whether an object is null or not before accessing it?

Tags: c#

for example,

```
if(method1().method2().method3().method4().method5().object != null)
{
 var value =  method1().method2().method3().method4().method5().object;
}
```

I have came across and written many such scenarios in c#, (ex:- while working with selenium frameworks) where a specific object can only be access through a long chain of method callings, and having to check for null before accessing objects value to not get exceptions. Feels like above code is bit too redundant. What coding pattern is/are used to make above code better? How to not write method calling chain 2 times ?

Comment: what about using null conditional operator --- `method1()?.method2()?.method3()?.method4()?.method5()?.object`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: @user1672994 thanks, im not aware of the syntax will check it out

Comment: @user1672994: If the sample code provided is accurate, that's not the problem - it looks like nothing in the chain can be null. Of course, it's entirely possible that the sample code isn't representative of the actual issue.

Comment: That's the "Train wreck" anti-pattern. See for example https://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck

Comment: Smells like code smell...https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/csharp/example

Answer (score 2):

Even before C# 7, you could just use a local variable:

```cs
var something = method1().method2().method3().method4().method5().object;
if (something != null)
{
    // Use something
}
```

In C# 7+ you can also use a pattern:

```cs
if (method1().method2().method3().method4().method5().object is object value)
{
    // Use value
}
```

Note that you *can't* use `var` for this; the `var` pattern matches against a null, whereas you want to *only* match if it's non-null. Just use the appropriate type. (We can't tell what it is from the question...)

Comment: I understand that the methods could return `null` in which case it would be good to use the null conditional operator (even if not it would be good, since that can always change).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't see any indication of that from the question. The OP presented what I assume is working code containing repetition that they want to remove - but which *doesn't* check the result of each method call for null. (And doing it "just in case" doesn't sit right with me - if a method doesn't return null, but starts doing so later, that could be for any number of reasons which might *not* want  to be handled in the same way as the final part being null.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: OP seems to refer just to `object`: _"having to check for null before accessing objects value to not get exceptions"_ However, with such a long chain of method calls, it's a good idea to handle the case that any of those methods could return `null` (even if not today, it might change tomorrow).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Again, if it changes, that doesn't mean any of those methods returning null should automatically be handled in the same way as `object` being null. I think `?.` should only be used *deliberately* when the consequences are known to be appropriate.

Comment: @JonSkeet: most times a`NullReferenceException` is not appropriate. This code is not responsible for the correct implementation of those methods. But it's responsible to handle the case that these methods return `null`. If appropriate OP can handle both case differently. So the case that `object` is `null` can be handled as normal use-case and the case that any of those methods returned `null` is an exceptional case that should be handled by logging. Hence store not `object` in a variable but the return value of those method calls and use the Null Conditional Operator

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'd rather have a `NullReferenceException` that alerts me to the problem than a *silent* change of behavior that may well be inappropriate. However, this is *definitely* beyond the scope of what was actually being asked, and so I'm not going to comment any further. It's fine for us to disagree about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the null conditional operator with a local variable. That would save the 2nd call and also checking the null at each method return. You can read about null conditional operator at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

```
var result = method1()?.method2()?.method3()?.method4()?.method5()?.object;
if(result != null)
{
    var value =  result ;
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: i'd store the return value of `method5` in a variable not `object`. Then you can handle the cases that these methods returned `null`(maybe log it)  or `object` is `null`(expected) differently